# I can't find an error in my first switch statement

Tags: c++, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I'm reading the book programming principles and practice using C++ and the book has introduced the concept of switch statement and an example of what we can do when we want to perform the same action for a series of case labels :

```
cout << "Please enter a digit : "; 
char a = 0; 
cin >> a; 

switch (a) {

case '0': case '2': case '4': case '6': case '8':
cout << "is even\n"; 
break; 

case '1': case '3': case '5': case '7': case '9':
cout << "is odd\n"; 
break;

default:
    cout << "is not a digit\n"; 
    break; 
}
```

The compiler doesn't report any error but when i execute the program if I enter the value 11 for example the program prints out : is odd. Why ? I expected to see : is not a digit but I can't understand where the problem is. This problem happens also if I enter the value 999 or some other values, why ?

Comment: May be you should consider revisiting the previous chapters

Comment: You need to study on the difference between character one, '1', and number 1.  Hint:  See ASCII chart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You read a *single* character, `'1'`. 1 is odd.

The next character is still there to be read.

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << "Please enter a digit : ";
```

You are asking user to enter a digit. Why are you storing it in `char`?:

```
char a = 0;
```

You need to store it in an `int`:

```
int a = 0;
```

Then all you `case`s have `char`s:

```
case '0': case '2': case '4': case '6': case '8':
```

This should be changed to `int`s:

```
case 0: case 2: case 4: case 6: case 8:
```

Similarly change for other cases.